# React-Native Application is crashing when running on physical device but not simulator

Tags: android, react-native, crash, apk, release

I am trying to run my react-native apk on my physical device but after I get past the login screen, it just crashes. I followed the steps in the documentation to sign the apk before doing `./gradlew assembleRelease` and then I sent it to my phone and I am trying to run the release apk not the debug one. The app doesn't crash right away but after I log in. It is important to note that the app working perfectly fine when running it with:

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

I also cannot see the logs for the device because for some reason my pixel2 XL will not show as a connected device on my computer. I've enabled the USB debugging, installed the Google Device driver, changed the default USB configuration and tried all the options in settings > Developer Options > Default USB Configuration but still cannot get it to connect. Also, I've noticed when I try to uninstall and reinstall the apk, it won't let me reinstall it. It just says 'App not installed.' I've been trying to figure this out for so long I thought I would reach out on here for some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use **instabug** to view and analyse release build errors. Here is the documentaion for integrating it with your app.[instabug react-native](https://instabug.com/platforms/react-native)

Answer (score 0):

- Android studio show you a cause of crashing, this way you can check your crash logs.

> Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor

- There sort of way to uninstall app but I would suggest use *adb* command line and run below command in your terminal.

> adb uninstall `<your package name>`

Comment: My device is not recognized by my computer for some reason so I can't check the logs....

Comment: You can check your release build in Android emulator.

Comment: What would that do? And how would I know what release build should be used?